# Cordava application is not working on android studio 3.1

Tags: android, cordova

Unable to find a matching configuration of project :CordovaLib:

- Configuration 'debugApiElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
- Configuration 'debugBundleElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but no value provided.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but no value provided.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'android-bundle'.
- Configuration 'debugMetadataElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but no value provided.
- Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
- Configuration 'releaseApiElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
- Configuration 'releaseBundleElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but no value provided.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but no value provided.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'android-bundle'.
- Configuration 'releaseMetadataElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but no value provided.
- Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':

  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.